# Why does implementing INotifyPropertyChanged avoid memory leaks in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I read about how memory leaks can be avoided in **Windows Presentation Foundation** apps, by binding only properties that either implements INotifyPropertyChanged or they are DependencyObject objects. But how does that make the CLR to collect this objects?

Source info:

> WPF Bindings can actually cause memory leaks. The rule of thumb is to always bind to a DependencyObject or to a INotifyPropertyChanged object. When you fail to do so, WPF will create a strong reference to your binding source (meaning the ViewModel) from a static variable, causing a memory leak (https://michaelscodingspot.com/ways-to-cause-memory-leaks-in-dotnet/)

Comment: Try searching StackOverflow for `[wpf] INotifyPropertyChanged memory leaks`

Comment: I found a number of posts on SO about this have dead links or not terribly useful links. There's an explanation of why you (potentially) get a leak here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a property does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, then the WPF framework will stupidly add one for you by subscribing to the PropertyDescriptor.ValueChanged event.  Since WPF and the CLR do not know when to dispose of / unsubscribe from the event, it holds on to the property forever.  And since the property is being referenced, it can not be garbage collected.  The whole instance of the class that contains that property stays in memory forever, thus causing a memory leak.

Comment: You write "if a _property_ does not implement the INPC interface" when actually _objects_ must implement the interface to notify WPF when a property has changed. Now I wonder: if I have a UserControl with a (readonly) `public object Test {get;}`property that I bind to from Xaml - will that cause a memory leak, if the UserControl does not (additionally) implement INPC? (Of course, if the property were to change I would need INPC - or implement it as a DependencyProperty.)

Comment: There is no ValueChanged event on PropertyDescriptor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor?view=net-7.0. What exactly are you referring to? I have doubts this is correct.