# Can binding to a struct's property cause memory leaks in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, struct, memory-leaks, binding

Consider the following `struct` and `class`:

```
public struct DemoStruct
{
    public DemoStruct(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    
    public int Value {get; }
}


public class DemoClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DemoStruct _demo;
    public DemoStruct Demo 
    {
        get => _demo;
        set {_demo = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Demo)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And, assuming the `DataContext` is an instance of `DemoClass`, consider this binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Demo.Value}"/>
```

By now I've learned that binding to an object that is not a `DependencyObject` or does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` can cause a memory-leak, see e.g. [Why does implementing INotifyPropertyChanged avoid memory leaks in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772492/why-does-implementing-inotifypropertychanged-avoid-memory-leaks-in-wpf).

What I'm wondering is how WPF will handle binding to a `struct` property.

My `DemoStruct` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because it is an immutable struct.

I'm assuming it will be boxed by WPF, but will this also create a memory leak, due to the "strong reference" to the boxed `struct` instance?

And, since a new box will be created whenever WPF accesses the property - will these all leak?

And, a follow up to be on the safe side:

If I were to change the binding to:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Demo}"/>
```

Despite the boxing, this should not cause a leak, because WPF does not have to attach any event handlers to "Demo" - right?

Comment: The answer is possibly, yes.  Binding to something does not implement inotifypropertychanged can cause memory leaks.

Comment: You can implement an interface in a record.

Comment: @Andy: yes, but if were not stuck with C# 7.3, because we're using .NET Framework...

Comment: Ah.  Well I would go with a class then mate. If you bind Demo, what are you expecting it to return to the target? You'd need a converter to do anything much with it wouldn't you?

Comment: The struct is, because I would like to avoid heap allocation (where it is actually used, regardless of WPF/UI). Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` should fix the issue; i was just wondering...

Comment: If it's a public property in a class then it's on the heap, isn't it? I always get a bit confused exactly what circumstance something is definitely on the stack.  Doesn't it have to be a method variable?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, class fields that contain a struct technically live on the heap, but as part of their class' memory, so they do not explicitly need to be GC'd. Boxed structs, however, take part in GCing as any other object does. So I always assume "lives on the heap" implies the latter case: an object that needs to be GC'd.

Comment: @mike: Does the view model `DemoClass` outlive the window? Then clear the bindings or reset the `DataContext`. Did you detect an actual leak?

Comment: While your understanding is generally correct, you must understand that this is not a bad leak in a sense that the rooted object is big or the rooted reference tree is deep. It's a very very tiny struct. It's not an error to not implement the interface. It just introduces a performance penalty especially in terms of memory footprint. The point is, if you don't create thousands of instances (because you are updating the Demo property frequently) you can chose to live with a few rooted bytes (`int` value plus the `ValueType` overhead). You can decide. I personally wouldn't bother to implement it

Comment: But if you like to bind to a struct you don't have access to its source code like `Point`, you can either pay the tiny cost or wrap it into a read-only  property (`public double X => _point.X`).

Comment: @BionicCode: If I understood you correctly, implementing INPC "introduces a performance penalty especially in terms of memory footprint" - why? And: yes, Demo will be updated very frequently (10-100x/s) and the application may run for a long time (days).

Comment: *"It's not an error to not implement the interface. It just introduces a performance penalty especially in terms of memory footprint. "* - This means *not implementing INPC* introduces the performance penalty. You wrote *"Demo will be updated very frequently (10-100x/s)"* - In this case you probably shouldn't use a struct. You should modify the same instance of a reference type. It will be cheaper in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: You wrote *"Yes, class fields that contain a struct technically live on the heap, but as part of their class' memory, so they do not explicitly need to be GC'd"* - The struct is created on the heap, not the field. The field is a variable (instance or class variable) that points to the struct on the heap. In this case the struct will be explicitly garbage collected, of course. The GC will walk down the reference graph to collect the eligible objects. In case another reference to the struct exist, the GC would skip the collection of the struct until all references are eligible for collection.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, they can do. Unless you use mode=onetime bindings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

The struct itself will not cause memory leaks.

Properties on that struct would do.

Demo is a property in a class that implements Inotifypropertychanged. If you bound to Demo then that would not cause a leak but you get a struct. That might not be terribly useful.

If you bind to Demo.Value then that's a property on a struct and that will cause a hard reference to be created. Unless....

Since Demo is to be immutable then maybe in your use case you could try a onetime binding. That doesn't then care about any property changing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/jgoldb/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications

If you switch out Demo then you could consider a converter to read the data out value. Bind to Demo and use a converter which would then read Value and return that. Might be a bit clunky if you had more than one property.

You could alternatively wrap Demo.Value with another property in your viewmodel. Raise propertychanged on wrapper property when demo changes.

Comment: But, if I use one time binding for "{Binding Demo.Value}", then it will also not update/respond when the "Demo" property of the DataSource changes...

Comment: @mike then you could maybe template out demo or use a converter as I mentioned. Or write your own binding mechanism.  (gulp) I'd have to know much more about the use case to give specifics.

Comment: @mike or you could wrap your demo value with another regular property.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your input, but I will probably go for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` just to satisfy WPF. It won't be the first time. Just this time it's especially awkward, considering the struct is immutable and the event will never be used.

Comment: Note: Using an actual `readonly struct` (to underline the immutable idea) will cause error "Field-like events are not allowed in readonly structs".

Comment: Btw @mike you can use records with older versions of .net. So long as you use a newish version of visual studio. https://sergiopedri.medium.com/enabling-and-using-c-9-features-on-older-and-unsupported-runtimes-ce384d8debb

Comment: Nice tip, see also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKa-tjnUMA